# webrtc app show my Turn server broken, but it works

Tags: webrtc, apache2.4, turn, coturn

I have my stun / turn server running on local pc (CoTurn). It is tested on "https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/" and works. I have a domain name and configured the modem with public ip. I configured apache2 to make the site visible to the world. I have active and valid letsencript certificates. Everything works in short. But the test application starts the connection (the external pc communicates with the local via socket.io) but then the video is not seen and the console returns the error: ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details.

The link of the application that I use as a test, because with my original I had no comparisons to make. First time with socket.io. But socket.io send and receive messages so these not appear a problem for now.

https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example

P.S.:

Ok. Server is behind the nat. My app (but linked app too) work very fine on local network (sorry I checked this point first before). These with my turn/stun server, than with public stun/turns google servers. This evidently indicates a bad setting of apache2 server or/and turn server. Where could I find a guide about it?

My server situation: myServerIpLocal-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> nat/router/modem WithPublicIpStatic-xx.xx.xx.xx. I can see my sites from all the world, but turn server not work outside the local network. Inside local network work ok.

these my turn config:

```html
listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=5349
alt-listening-port=3479
alt-tls-listening-port=5350
listening-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /*mylocal ip*/
relay-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /*mylocal ip*/
external-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx /*my public ip on nat/ruter/modem */

min-port=49152
max-port=65535
verbose
fingerprint

userdb=/var/lib/turn/turndb
realm=mysite.com
cert=/etc/ssl/certificate.pem
pkey=/etc/ssl/private.key
dh-file=/etc/turn/dhparam.pem
no-stdout-log
log-file=/myhome/.turn/turn.log

lt-cred-mech
user=myusername:mypasswd

# Turn OFF the CLI support.
# By default it is always ON.
# See also options cli-ip and cli-port.
#
no-cli

#Local system IP address to be used for CLI server endpoint. Default value
# is 127.0.0.1.
#
cli-ip=127.0.1.1

# CLI server port. Default is 5766.
#
cli-port=5766

# CLI access password. Default is empty (no password).
#
cli-password=logen

no-sslv3
no-tlsv1
```

Answer (score 1):

my old code on turn.conf:

`lt-cred-mech
user=myusername:mypasswd`

but turn work only locally .... probabily because I use: 
 `sudo turnserver -L myPublicIp -o -a myrealm` 
at every coturn start command ....

actually I try not use the command "turnserver" and I try to use onlu sudo coturn start .....

basically in my turn.conf file I change these:

`lt-cred-mech
user=mypasswd:myusername  /***** mind the gap ;) *****/`

these because my index.js file debug never see my external connection as authrized user ..... magically at these time my app perform webrtc multiple connection with every pc and mobile .... inside and outside my lan .... (I try connect my appa from phone in barcelona spain to other one in london with good result).

May be coturn wiki need to update?

Finally I would like to thank the serverfault and super-user guys who rejected my question. Since I had to make arrangements, I was able to acquire new and interesting information on this subject.

regards