# unable to connect to Coturn server

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I am following the official [coturn docs](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/CoturnConfig) and trying to setup a `coturn` server to handle `STUN` and `TURN` requests. I am testing if my server runs correctly by using this little JS script:

```
function checkTURNServer(turnConfig, timeout){ 

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved) return;
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if(promiseResolved || !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !(ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')>-1))  return;
      promiseResolved = true;
      resolve(true);
    };
  });   
}
```

and running it with my credentials:

```
checkTURNServer({"url":"turn:IP1:3478",'username': 'bayaz',"credential":"magi"}).then(function(bool){
    console.log('is TURN server active? ', bool? 'yes':'no');
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Where the user was created with;

```
turnadmin -A -u bayaz -p magi
```

This are uncommented lines in configuration file:

```
listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=5349
listening-ip=IP1
listening-ip=IP2    
verbose 
lt-cred-mech
realm=mydomain.com
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
```

This is the output of running `turnserver -c path/to/file.conf`

```
0: log file opened: /var/tmp/turn_10200_2019-05-17.log
0: Listener address to use: IP1
0: Listener address to use: IP2
0: 
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.8 'dan Eider'
0: 
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 4096
0: 
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 2000 (approximately)
0: 

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 (0x100020bf)
0: 
0: SQLite supported, default database location is /usr/local/var/db/turndb
0: Redis is not supported
0: PostgreSQL is not supported
0: MySQL is not supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: 
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Domain name: 
0: Default realm: mydomain.com
0: SSL23: Certificate file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
0: SSL23: Private key file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
0: TLS1.0: Certificate file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
0: TLS1.0: Private key file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
0: TLS1.1: Certificate file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
0: TLS1.1: Private key file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
0: TLS1.2: Certificate file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
0: TLS1.2: Private key file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
0: TLS cipher suite: DEFAULT
0: DTLS: Certificate file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
0: DTLS: Private key file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
0: DTLS1.2: Certificate file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
0: DTLS1.2: Private key file found: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
0: DTLS cipher suite: DEFAULT
0: Relay address to use: IP1
0: Relay address to use: IP2
Cannot create pid file: /var/run/turnserver.pid: Permission denied
0: Cannot create pid file: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: pid file created: /var/tmp/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay IP1 initialization...
0:   relay IP1 initialization done
0:   relay IP2 initialization...
0:   relay IP2 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=1 created
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP1:3479
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:3479
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP1:5350
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:5350
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP2:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP2:3479
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:3479
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP2:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : IP2:5350
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:5350
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:3479
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP1:5350
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:3479
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : IP2:5350
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP1:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP1:3479
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP1:5349
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP1:5350
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP2:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP2:3479
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP2:5349
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: IP2:5350
0: Total General servers: 2
0: IO method (admin thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766
0: SQLite DB connection success: /usr/local/var/db/turndb
```

When I test my turn server, I get my custom error message `"is TURN server active?  no"` in the console, which indicated that I got no response from the server.

I already spent a few days trying to figure this out, but I had no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `{"urls":`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl start coturn
```

is the EASY way to do the things ... for sure you can use turnserver command, but the right command for yous situaton is not so easy to do.
With that command you can start the turn.conf server, witouth other problem .... these is my config [webrtc app show my Turn server broken, but it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065147/webrtc-app-show-my-turn-server-broken-but-it-works) ... I use it with dns in local server apache2 with redirect and proxy, all traffic UDP all on 443 port (not for turnsturn obviusly). Coturn is 4.5. Note no-cli and all cli option ... if I use only no-cli option, server not run. Read my reply too.

Comment: Thanks man! I see I am not the only one puzzled by the coturn. At first, `turnserver` was not configured to be used as a service, so thanks for pointing that out. I used this link (https://support.ladesk.com/536840-STUNTURN-servers)  to make the `coturn.service` file. I can now start the coturn with `systemctl start coturn` and `systemctl status coturn` is happily displaying that the coturn is running.

Comment: I tried stun connecting using stunclient direclty from my server (https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnutils_stunclient) and it connected without any problem. However, I still can't connect from my local machine

Comment: I installed coturn on my laptop and tried `turnutils_stunclient remoteIP` and never got an answer. In short, coturn works locally on the server, but not for remote connections.

Comment: sorry but please control your modem/router config, your firewall rules, your server roules .... you are on ubuntu try these ... well done: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html

Comment: I've visited that link a couple of times in the last days :D I am on centos and that guide doesn't seem to do the trick. I've managed to start a TURN server after playing with `iptables` and adding password as you did. However, I never managed to make a STUN connection. I opened another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208929/coturn-stun-requests-work-locally-but-not-for-remote-connections